# Are fundamental groups of Riemann surfaces always finitely generated

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves, covering-spaces

For any finite subset $B\subset \mathbf{P}^1$, the fundamental group of the Riemann surface $\mathbf{P}^1-B$ is finitely generated.

Is this true if we replace $\mathbf P^1 $ by a higher genus compact connected Riemann surface?

More precisely, let $B\subset X$ be a finite subset of a compact connected Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g>0$. Is the fundamental group of $X-B$ finitely generated?

Comment: I don't think this is true. But it is true that they're countable.

Comment: http://touch-geometry.karazin.ua/list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is finitely generated. On the level of homotopy, removing a finite set is equivalent to removing finitely many open disks. There is a well-known classification of surfaces with boundary. They are all homeomorphic to a disk with several bands attached, which is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of circles, so the fundamental group is actually a free group of finite rank if there is at least one puncture. If there are no punctures, then the group is no longer free but still finitely generated.

Answer (score 6):

The complement of a non-empty finite set in a closed (real!) manifold of dimension $2$ has the homotopy type of a finite graph, so the answer is yes.

This is easy to see if you know that all such manifolds can be obtained by identifying the sides of a plane polygon.