# Is the fundamental group of a compact surface finitely generated?

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, manifolds, fundamental-groups

I would like to use that the fundamental group $π_1(M)$ of a compact surface $M$ possibly with boundary has a finite set of generators. According to [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116759/are-fundamental-groups-of-riemann-surfaces-always-finitely-generated) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93330/why-is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-riemann-surface-not-free) here and sources elsewhere², it sounds like this is well-known but I couldn't find a proof or reference anywhere. Do you know one?

²[Consider only closed](https://www.labri.fr/perso/vdelecro/infflatsurf/infflatsurf-chap2_top_and_geom-mar2019.pdf) [(i.e. boundary-less) surfaces](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2013/REUPapers/Actipes.pdf)

Comment: Section 17c (p. 242) of *Algebraic Topology A first course* from 1995 by William Fulton states what I want but I am not sure if it considers manifolds with boundaries as well since this "normal form" that is used looks like only for boundaryless (closed) surfaces.

Comment: Generally speaking, the fundamental group of a compact manifold (possibly with boundary) is finitely presented, because a compact manifold is homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex (see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118429/fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold). In this case it suffices to show that a compact surface admits a (finite) triangulation, and for that see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33321/why-do-all-compact-connected-surfaces-have-a-triangulation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the fundamental group of a compact manifold finitely presented?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented) For surfaces, it is a standard algebraic topology exercise to compute finite presentations of fundamental groups. You can find a proof in pretty much every AT textbook (Hatcher, Massey, etc). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995381/fundamental-group-of-surface-of-genus-g

Comment: The fundamental group of any finite simplicial complex is finitely generated because it can be described as the "edge-path group": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group#Edge-path_group_of_a_simplicial_complex. Any compact surface can be given the structure of a finite simplicial complex (i.e., triangulated), as the comment by @QiaochuYuan says.

Comment: Thank you for the references and the link to the suitable question which I didn't find beforehand. Now I cannot "accept" your answer but thanks!